# C / C++ conventions/toolchains for library compilation

Tags: c++, compilation

**My basic problem with C/C++ lies in the area of library compilation.** E.g. software A uses library Z, thus you have to compile library Z before you can compile and subsequently use and/or develop software A.

In many cases there is this notion of configuring the project and then calling make + make install. E.g. you open your command line and enter:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

`./configure` is a shell script placed in the top-level directory of the project. I suppose it checks whether all dependencies are present on the system and saves the paths to these dependencies. Later, make can make use of this collected information to provide the compiler with the respective include paths and library locations (e.g. locations of .so/.a files).

`make` is responsible for compiling and linking the source files in the correct order (as specified by makefiles, which are generated by I-dont-know and have format XYZ). Of course, it doesn't compile/link anything itself, it rather calls the actual compiler and linker to do its work.

`make install` takes the resulting binary files and places them somewhere in the system (e.g. /usr/lib if the project is a library or /usr/bin for executables). If the project at hand is a library, it supposedly also takes the library's header files and installs them somewhere in the system.

This is a relative complex process; let's use CMI to denote this type of compilation process (CMI = configure-make-install). Also, the CMI concept is - as far as I can tell - specific for the Linux world. It doesn't work like that on Windows, e.g. because there is no shell which you could use to execute ./configure. make might even be limited to gcc/g++, but I do not know whether that is the case.

Most importantly, I do not even know where to look that up. I would also like to look up whether the CMI concept supports installing different versions of libraries at the same time. Imagine you're a developer of software B and software C. Software B and C both depend on library Y, but B requires Y 1.0.x and C requires 1.1.x, for whatever reason. If make install places the library's header files somewhere on the system, won't there be collisions? Again, I ask my self, where can I look that up?

---

Let's discuss an example library: [libzip](http://nih.at/libzip/index.html). The homepage doesn't state what compilers or platforms are supported or recommended. How would you proceed now?

Interestingly, the page claims that MySQL Workbench is using libzip. MySQL Workbench is also offered for Windows, so I suppose that libzip can be compiled on Windows.

I also observe that libzip is shipped with a **CMakeLists.txt** *and* a **configure** script. There even is a **libzip.pc.in** CMake-template, supposedly for the **pkg-config** tool. There also is Makefile.am - whatever that is - and Makefile.in, supposedly another CMake-template. Last but not least I have noticed a folder m4 and .m4 files (both within the m4 folder and in the project's root folder). But let's not forget cmake-config.h.in, cmake-zipconf.h.in.

So, if you want to compile libzip, you have to consider the following alternatives:

- use the CMI concept

  - not applicable on Windows (right?)
- use CMake, which is a meta build system of sorts

  - then you have to decide what compiler/IDE CMake should generate for: gcc? MSVC? Mingw or QTSDK/MingW? (whatever the difference is)
- maybe use M4, whatever that is

M4 seems to be related to GNU autoconf. Which I could also add to the above list, I suppose.

(Sidenote: So far, I have tried compiling libzip using the combination of CMake + Visual Studio 2010. Currently I am fixing all sorts of compilation errors.)

---

**This is my central observation:**

libzip is a simple library; just some zip stuff. Yet, the compilation involves so many tools that it is an impossibly difficult task, even for advanced programmers.

Also, the documentation of most of these tools is lacking (else why do I have all of these questions, not knowing where to find the answer?). Not to mention that most of the tools don't even work without investing hours in reverse-engineering to fix, for instance, buggy CMake FindPackage-scripts *sigh*.

---

I could go on like that for WEEKS. I am lost in the multitude of compilation concepts, how all of them *relate to each other*, what platforms and compilers they work with well etc.

Another example: RetroShare. Even though the compilation process for Windows [is documented](http://retroshare.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Win32Compile), it is extremely difficult to accomplish the compilation. Just consider that compiling RetroShare on Windows involves QtSDK/MingW, Cygwin and MingW/MSYS, all of them for different parts/dependecies. How do these tools even work together?

I am completely lost and I would like you to tell me how you deal with this sort of problem and how you protect your mind from serious damage considering all of these tools/toolchains/compilers/platforms.

***Are you guys extremely intelligent or am I extremely stupid? Why is this so complex (or is it not)?***

Comment: Hello Robert and welcome to the club. :)

Comment: How is running `./configure; make; make install` an impossibly difficult task? The library coders are using autotools like that so you can run it on many many different OSes without having to know about the gory dependency details of the library.

Comment: tip: avoid the introduction you mention. Even if you think it is critical to the question, put it in the end, and not in the beginning, you are more likely to get more attention, because the first few lines of the question only appear in the questions page - so make them count!

Comment: @MarkB: That's the idea, but in my experience, it's almost never that simple, even in the *nix world, but especially if you are on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

> "I could go on like that for WEEKS."

You do sound a *slightly* confused.  I'll address a few specific points.

The "configure-make-install" process makes a particular use of `make`, which is a more general purpose tool.  Ie, make and makefiles can be used in other ways.  Keep that in mind.

> "make is responsible for compiling and linking the source files in the
>   correct order (as specified by makefiles, which are generated by
>   I-dont-know and have format XYZ)."

Sooner or later, you are almost certainly going to have to learn to write makefiles yourself.  Make is a build system, which is a pretty useful, near mandatory tool for a C/C++ programmer.  If you use an IDE, it may already be creating makefiles for you. Here's an example makefile written by hand for a small project:

```
wx = `wx-config --cxxflags --libs`

test1: main.cpp main.h window.o
        g++ -Wall -g main.cpp window.o -o test1 $(wx)

window.o: window.cpp window.h
        g++ -Wall -g -c window.cpp -o window.o $(wx)
```

The first line defines a variable, some flags for the linker, this is used twice after that.  The next two bits should be familiar if you use gcc on the command line.  To build this project without `make`, you would compile window.o first via `g++ ...` and then `test1`.  With the makefile in place, all you have to do is run `make`.  Add a few more object (.o) files to the project and it starts to seem very handy. Also, you can write different "**targets**" into one makefile. There are various make tutorials around, and the official docs for the GNU version:

http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html

It isn't hard to figure out.

> "make install takes the resulting binary files and places them
>   somewhere in the system"

`make install` is a **target** conventionally defined to do that in makefiles used in the configure-make-install context.  You could add such a thing to the makefile above:

```
install: test1
    cp test1 /usr/local/bin/
```

Whatever's on the same line as the target after the colon is a prerequisite -- it refers to a file that must be present in the build tree (or another target directive that must be run). If the file is not present (or if some of its prerequisites have changed since it was built) and there is a target with the same name (in this case, `test1` -- look at the prereqs from before too) then that target directive is run first.

> "Also, the CMI concept is - as far as I can tell - specific for the
>   Linux world."

No, but it is slightly alien to the windows world.  This is sometimes referred to in relation to **autotools**, which can be used to generate configure scripts and corresponding makefiles. Note that you can use CMI packages on windows if you have **mingw** installed.

> "use CMake, which is a meta build system of sorts"

CMake is essentially the same thing as make, only different.  `make` only uses gcc if it is explicitly invoked in the makefile; makefiles can be written to do just about anything a shell script can do, including running a compiler, etc.  CMake aspires to be more portable/platform agostic, and perhaps user friendly.  Some people like it better.

> "If make install places the library's header files somewhere on the system, won't there be collisions?"

Ideally, no.  Part of the point of the autotools ("CMI") setup is to allow the packager to implement mechanisms to deal with issues such as this if they exist.  You can have multiple versions of the same library installed.  WRT headers, if those change, they (hopefully) remain backward compatible, as does the library itself.  If not, there should be some explicit indication of this ("version 2 is not compatible with version 1!") and when that happens, anyone with a brain will have distinct headers for version 2 from the beginning and refer to that in the API.

Answer (score 0):

It is also could be helpful to understand what to use: http://www.elpauer.org/stuff/learning_cmake.pdf